# Gremlin to update meta properties of existing vertex

Tags: groovy, gremlin, janusgraph

I am create a vertex with its properties. Each property will have its meta-properties

```
// Define schema in Gemlin Console

// Create vertex
mgmt.makeVertexLabel('v01').make()

// Create properties
mgmt.makePropertyKey('p01').dataType(String.class).cardinality(LIST).make()

// Create meta-properties
mgmt.makePropertyKey('created_by').dataType(String.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey('created_date').dataType(String.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey('modified_by').dataType(String.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey('modified_date').dataType(String.class).cardinality(SINGLE).make()

// Insert data
p.addV('v01').
    property(list, 'p01', 'pvalue01', 'created_by', 'system01' ,'created_date', new Date(), 'modified_by', '', 'modified_date')
```

Meta properties info:

`created_by`: system name who created the property value

`created_date`: timestamp of created value

`modified_by`: system name who updated the property value

`modified_date`: timestamp of updated value

When property value `pvalue01` is added to property `p01`, only `created_by` and `created_date` have values while `modified_by` and `modified_date` have empty string.

If newer value `pvalue02` is added to property `p01`, how should I update the meta-properties (`modified_by` and `modified_date`) for `pvalue01`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the value of a meta property you simply have to locate it and use a `property` step to change its value. For example

```
g.V().hasLabel('v01').
    properties('p01').
    property('modified_date',new Date())
```

If you need to update multiple properties, the value returned from the `property` step is the Vertex Property, so you can chain them together.

```
g.V().hasLabel('v01').
    properties('p01').
    property('modified_date',new Date()).
    property('modified_by','Me')
```

UPDATED to add an example of how this works when `list` cardinality is in use:

```
gremlin> g.addV('V01').
           property(list,'mylist','pv1').
           property(list,'mylist','pv2')
==>v[60870]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V01').propertyMap()
==>[mylist:[vp[mylist->pv1],vp[mylist->pv2]]]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V01').properties('mylist')
==>vp[mylist->pv1]
==>vp[mylist->pv2]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V01').properties('mylist').hasValue('pv2')
==>vp[mylist->pv2]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V01').properties('mylist').hasValue('pv2').property('meta',123)
==>vp[mylist->pv2]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V01').properties('mylist').hasValue('pv2').properties()
==>p[meta->123]
```

Comment: if p01=[pvalue01, pvalue02], how do I update the meta property of the specific values?

Comment: I added an example to the answer.